# Why is the line BC equal to the trigonometric ratio $\tanθ$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Referring to the image

[image: unit_circle_diagram]

Is the tangent in trigonometry (ratio of two sides of a right triangle) the same as the tangent of a curve (the slope)?

If it is proven that BC = to the $\tanθ$, then that'll mean that the the ratio $\tan θ$ defines the slope of the curve at point $(\cosθ, \sinθ)$

Comment: $\tan(\theta)=\frac{\text{opposite side to}\theta}{\text{adjacent side to}\theta}=\frac{BC}{1}=BC$

Comment: Yes, the slope of a curve at a point is the tangent  (in the trigonometric sense) of the polar angle of the line tangent to the curve w.r.t. the $x$-axis

Comment: Ok but how is this so in the Image? If I take the triangle ABC and take the ratios w.r.t the angle at C, how is my hypotenuse (BC) equal to tanθ here?

Comment: Incidentally, a coordinate-wise way to look at it is to note that the line through $\vec{BC}$ has the parametrization $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)) + t\sin(\theta),-\cos(\theta))$. You can now ask for $t$ such that the $y$ coordinate is zero; you find that it is $\tan(\theta)$. This gives the coordinates of the point $C$ as $(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta) \tan(\theta),0)$. Then you can compute the distance BC as $\sqrt{\sin(\theta)^2 \tan(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2}=\tan(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

we can draw BD parallel to OA, or perpendicular to AB,so

$$\angle(AOB) = \angle(OBD) = \theta(T)$$
so 
$$ \angle(OBA) = \frac {\pi}2-T $$
and hence, 
$$ \angle(ABC) = T $$
Now, in triangle(ABC)
$$\cos (T) = \dfrac {\text {Base}}{\text {hypotenuse}} = \dfrac {\sin T}{\text {BC}}$$
On rearranging,we get

$$\text {BC} =  \tan T$$

Comment: Got it! Thanks man.

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your post.

Comment: K I'll use it from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle ABC$ are similar triangles, which implies

$\frac{BC}{1} = \frac {AB}{AO}$

Since $~~AB = sin~\theta~$, and $AO = cos~\theta~~~~~~$ ==> $~~~~~tan~\theta = BC$